# Uncaught TypeError: e(...).tabs is not a function

Tags: jquery, typescript, jquery-ui

I installed jquery-ui and @types/jqueryui. I am using webpack to generate a js file from ts. But I am unable to import @types/jqueryui as it it is not exported. I get the error in my browser console.

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';

$(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#tabset').tabs();
});
```

Comment: Since you're error is on the tabs and not on the document ready part, that would suggest that jQuery is defined, but jquery ui is not.  You need to make sure that is imported.

Comment: I tried importing as import 'jqueryui' which is @types/jqueryui package in node_modules. But it is an unexported namespace and does not consider as module and unable to import. I tried importing jquery-ui package too but not solving the error. In visual studio the intellisense is identifying the tabs function still iam getting the error. I am using webpack.